# Passing List<T> as parameter to WCF service operation

Tags: wcf, list

I have a WCF operation contract which looks like this:

```
public void SavePersons(List<Person> list, bool IsSelected)
{
}
```

I am passing it a strongly typed list of `Person` objects (`List<Person>`) in my client. However, I am getting a bad request 400 message when calling the service. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What kind of bindings are you using? We definitely need to see more than just this one line of code..... server- and client-side config (anything inside `<system.serviceModel>` would be a good place to start! And also the code on your client **how** you call this method

Comment: Did you decorate `Person` with DataContractAttribute `[DataContract]`?

Answer (score 2):

May I suggest you create you create a contract to encapsulate the parameters like so:

```
public void SavePersons(PersonCollectionContract Request)
{
    ...
}

[DataContract]
public class PersonCollectionContract
{
    [DataContract]
    public List<Person> People { get; set; }

    [DataContract]
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Person
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Ok, I got the thing narrowed down a bit. The WCF service received a list<Person> and I need to convert an observablecollection to a list before passing it to WCF service. I have an observablecollection<T> which I need to cast it to List<T> which the service expects. How do you go about this?

Comment: @onkarkulkarni. Include the LINQ namespace `using System.Linq;` and do `var list = obsColl.ToList();`.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar problem in passing a `List<Health>` of class Health type as a parameter to a wcf service method. I created a data contract in wcf service as below:

```
[DataContract]
public class Health
{
  ...
}
```

Defined a method in wcf service class such as:

```
public string GetData(List<Health> healthValues)
```

In my client application, while configuring/updating the service, I followed these steps:

- Add/Update URL
- Under Data Type (in Advanced), selected option, Collection type: System.Collection.Generic.List

And finally, I created a list and added the code in client as follows:

```
List<WcfService.Health> listHealth = new List<WcfService.Health>();
WcfService.Health h = new WcfService.Health();
.
.
listHealth.Add(h);
WcfService.Service1Client s = new WcfService.Service1Client();
string str = s.GetData(listHealth);
```

This solved my purpose and I was able to send the data as a list through wcf service.